# Loop through all rows and concat unique values in SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, foreach, grouping

I have two table that I want to merge.

Table 1 consisting of many rows, below are a few-

```
col1   col2  col3  col4

val1   val2  val3  val4
val1   val2  val3  val5
val1   val2  val3  val6
valx   valy  valz  val4
valx   valy  valz  val5
```

(val* are all strings)

Table 2 consists of unique rows (around 1000 of them) - 
    col1   col2  col3  col4

```
val1   val2  val3  -
valx   valy  valz  -
vala   valy  valz  -
```

I want to merge the two tables such that, Table 2 is the following -

```
col1   col2  col3  col4

val1   val2  val3  val4,val5,val6
valx   valy  valz  val4,val5
vala   valy  valz  -
```

Foreach row in table 2, I want to find the unique values for col4 table 1 and concat them

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What version of oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could concat as string aggregation using the format for your `Table1`,

```
SELECT col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     listagg(col4, ',') within GROUP(
ORDER BY col4) AS col4
FROM agg_test
GROUP BY col1,
     col2,
     col3;
```

You could get the result as:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
______________________________________    
val1    val2    val3    val4,val5,val6
valx    valy    valz    val4,val5
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting is a multivalued column named col4 in table2. Oracle doesn't support multivalued column. What you can do is create another column with foreign key to table2 and save your multivalued data over there.

For e.g.

```
Table 3

table2_id value
1         val4
1         val5
1         val6
2         val4
2         val5
```

Comment: It doesnt have to be a multivalued column. Can just concat as a string?